# Regex find and replace wildcard link

Tags: regex

Im stuck in the mud with using regex, but maybe someone can help me.

I have a tag within my pages that I need to change the URL within the tag, ie.

From:

```
<link href="/*.html" rel="canonical"/>
```

To:

```
<link href="https:/www.domain.com/*.html" rel="canonical"/>
```

The asterisk (*) = this is a global search through all my html files, the subdirectory can vary.

The regex i tried to use was: `href=”/([^"<]*)”`

It finds nothing. Very frustrating.

Comment: First, you need to escape the `*` with a backslash as `*` has a special meaning in regex. Same with your double quotes. Definitely look at one of the many tutorials on regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Sample file:

```
<link href="/*.html" rel="canonical"/>
<link href="/foobar.html" rel="canonical"/>
<link href="/bar/foobar.html" rel="canonical"/>
<link href="/bar/baz/foobar.tar.gz.html" rel="canonical"/>
```

Command:

```
sed -r 's/<link href="\/([^<]+).html" rel=/<link href="https:\/www.domain.com\/\1.html" rel=/' canon.html
```

Result:

```
<link href="https:/www.domain.com/*.html" rel="canonical"/>
<link href="https:/www.domain.com/foobar.html" rel="canonical"/>
<link href="https:/www.domain.com/bar/foobar.html" rel="canonical"/>
<link href="https:/www.domain.com/bar/baz/foobar.tar.gz.html" rel="canonical"/>
```

Command deconstruction:

- `sed -r 's`
- sed invocation, -r to make () work without masking, s:= substitute command
- `/<link href="\/([^<]+).html" rel=/`
- pattern between / to match, most of it literally except
- `([^<]+)` preventing greedy proceeding into next tag
- `<link href="https:\/www.domain.com\/\1.html" rel=/`
- mostly literal replacement, except
- `\1`
- the matched, first (and only) group of the pattern
- `canon.html`
- sample file name

Which characters need masking? Well, for sed, you need to mask the slashes, since they are used to split

```
command/pattern/replacement/parameters(optional)
```

Most probably your regex doesn't needs them. For example, in Java it would be

```
(file as String).replaceAll (pattern, replacement);
```

or something like that. And as pointed out in the comments, \1 would be $1 there. But there, you would need to mask the double quotes.

In an editors search/replace boxes, you usually have different textfields to separate the the elements and less masking. Parameters, which didn't apply here, are solved by checkboxes (upper/lowercase ignore etc.).

Comment: Thank you for the help but Im not using ssh for regex, but through dreamweaver or sublime. And I cant use it in the fashion you presented unfortunately

Comment: Well - it's sed, not ssh, but the Regexes are pretty similar on the basic level. In Java, it's $1 instead of \1 for example. What is the concrete problem? I don't know the fine details of dreamweaver or sublime.

Comment: Why would you chose `/` as the delimiter for your regex when literal `/` are within the regex requiring escaping? Use something like underscore `_` or comma `,` (or whatever) so your regex is more readable.

Comment: Because I learned it from Herold, "Sed & AWK", and he used this delimiters, if I remember correctly, constantly, if not exclusively. I learned only few months ago, that alternative delimiters are possible, but then they behave differently if used in scripts or interactively in bash, and I didn't investigate what is governing those differences.

Comment: Figured it out finally! Here is the proper regex that I needed:

<link(.*?)href="\/(.*?)(\/|\.html)"(.*?)>

Comment: @MarcusArkan: From your single sample, it wasn't possible to figure out, that you need that regex. I hope the next time, you have learned enough to solve it by yourself from scratch, or how to provide a representative data sample to make better guesses.

Comment: I appreciate all your help and assistance. I will clarify my notes better next time. Thank you